# jQuery plugin is not working(depends-on)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dependsOn-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function) {
    $('#basicTest .subject').dependsOn({
        '#basicTest input[type="checkbox"]': {
        checked: true
      }
    });
});
</script
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="basicTest">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me
    </label>
 
    <input type="text" class="subject">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am actually trying to implement the basic example which is  after click on the "check me" a input box gets displayed. By using the depends on plugin is is not working. These are the files. I placed the script in between the html and head tags. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: are you sure you have the given files in the correct directories?

Comment: 'Not working' is far too vague. Please at least check the console for errors

Comment: The files are in my home directory @N.Ivanov

Comment: Your code works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/Lejgx9oa/. Therefore it's more than likely you've made a mistake with the paths to the JS files, or you need to wrap your jQuery code in a document.ready event handler, presuming you've placed it in the `<head>` of your HTML

Comment: They are no errors but the output is displaying the text box before  click the "check me". @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Actually I placed the links in html tag and the script code in head tag is it correct way?

Comment: No, only `head` and `body` tags can contain `script` tags.

Comment: Can you elaborate where the files has to be placed?

Comment: Still not working after adding document.ready event handler @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You must have the HTML structure incorrect then. I've updated the fiddle to show you how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/Lejgx9oa/1/

Comment: Thankyou. It is working :)